# Can't restart NGINX server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to restart my NGINX server but it fails. When I type `nginx -t` I get the following result. I am running virtual server blocks using Ubuntu 14.04 on this droplet.

I appear to have a duplicate file, but I can seem to figure out how to solve this problem ?

```html
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/05/08 15:11:37 [warn] 1966#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2016/05/08 15:11:37 [emerg] 1966#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/realbadrabbits.com:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
>
> 2016/05/08 15:11:37 [warn] 1966#0: the "user" directive makes sense
> only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Those two are mostlikely due to the fact that you are not running your `nginx -t` as root. Try `sudo nginx -t`

Now the 3rd line is slightly different it's an actual issue in the config.

> 2016/05/08 15:11:37 [emerg] 1966#0: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/realbadrabbits.com:21

It means that the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/realbadrabbits.com` on line `21` has got `default_server` directive. And this is duplicated, most likely you still have your `default.conf` on you box or somewhere else in different vhost config you are using `default_server` directive.

Comment: Yes that was it thank you! Having five sites on one droplet is proving to be a bit of a tangled mess :)